Matplotlib: Stacked Bar Diagram
Image in this Image I want to split each bar as a stacked graph.
Sample data:
season   venue                                      toss_decision
2011/12  Shere Bangla National Stadium, Mirpur      bat first        12
                                                    field first      12
         Zahur Ahmed Chowdhury Stadium, Chittagong  bat first         5
                                                    field first       3
2016/17  Shere Bangla National Stadium, Mirpur      bat first        14
                                                    field first      21
         Zahur Ahmed Chowdhury Stadium, Chittagong  bat first         5
                                                    field first       6

I want to stacked them according to bat first and field first. But each bar must represent the venue as shown in the image. It just needed to be partitioned.
Code I've done:

# Plotting
pivot_df.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(7, 3), width=0.3)

plt.title('Win Counts by Venue and Toss Decision')
plt.xlabel('Venue')
plt.ylabel('Win Counts')
plt.xticks(rotation=360)
plt.legend(title='Toss Decision')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


You need to group the data accordingly before making the plot. This should work.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Grouping the data by season, venue, and toss decision for stacking
df_grouped = df.groupby(['season', 'venue', 'toss_decision'])['count'].sum().unstack()

# Plotting the stacked bar chart
ax = df_grouped.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, figsize=(10, 5))
ax.set_ylabel('Win Counts')
ax.set_xlabel('Venue')
ax.set_title('Win Counts by Venue and Toss Decision')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha="right")
plt.show()

